# Is it possible to delay the Execution of OpenCL Kernels until after all have been submitted?

Tags: opencl

I have a program that (with the details abstracted away) looks something like this:

```
std::vector<cl::Event> events;
for (uint32_t x = 0; x < image_size.x; x += 32) {
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < image_size.y; y += 32) {
        events.emplace_back();
        cl::Event * event_ptr = &events.back();
        cl::NDRange range{ cl::size_type(std::min(image_size.x - x, kernel_size)), cl::size_type(std::min(image_size.y - y, kernel_size)) };
        cl::NDRange offset{ cl::size_type(x), cl::size_type(y) };
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, offset, range, {}, nullptr, event_ptr);
    }
}
```

The intent is that later on, when the host has finished its tasks, it can then query the saved events individually, especially when waiting on all events to finish:

```
for(cl::Event const& event : events) {
    event.wait();
}
/*...*/
```

But in my testing, I've found that `enqueueNDRangeKernel` will start blocking once a critical mass of events have been queued up, and events will be running while I'm still trying to enqueue them. Is there a way to prevent any kernels from running until I explicitly want them to start? Something like

```
//PSEUDOCODE
cl::waitEvent trigger;
queue.enqueueWaitEvent(&trigger);

std::vector<cl::Event> events;
for (uint32_t x = 0; x < image_size.x; x += 32) {
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < image_size.y; y += 32) {
        events.emplace_back();
        cl::Event * event_ptr = &events.back();
        cl::NDRange range{ cl::size_type(std::min(image_size.x - x, kernel_size)), cl::size_type(std::min(image_size.y - y, kernel_size)) };
        cl::NDRange offset{ cl::size_type(x), cl::size_type(y) };
        queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, offset, range, {}, nullptr, event_ptr);
    }
}

trigger.release(); //All other events behind this event now start running.
/*...*/
```

But I don't know whether such a mechanism exists in OpenCL, or what that syntax would look like. I'm aware that I could probably achieve this functionality in Vulkan, but I'm targeting older hardware that doesn't have Driver support for Vulkan.

Comment: You can try user events. Ready a user event and a marker to wait for it as the first item of queue, then enqueue as many commands as you wish, flush the command queue to ensure queue is pushing to gpu, then when you need to push all at once, trigger the user event.

Comment: If it is opencl 2.x, you can use atomics with svm to lock from host side in a dummy kernel, then release it from host again.

Comment: Why are you processing your image in many 32x32 blocks? Can't you just process the whole thing with one large global work size? Second, if you have an in-order command queue and you're enqueuing many things, you only need to take an Event from the last one. There's no value in taking events for the earlier ones.

Comment: @Dithermaster It should be obvious that the code I've provided is example code, and meant to be a stand-in for much more complicated code.

Comment: You can make the first or all kernels wait for a user event, and only trigger than user event after your enqueuing loop, but if your runtime has some limit on the number of items you can enqueue before blocking, your enqeuue loop will block and you'll never get to trigger the user event. See clCreateUserEvent.

Comment: @Dithermaster Good to know. I've run tests using upwards of 3.6k kernel executions that are not triggered until the user event fires, and it *seemed* to work. I'll need to research whether there's a way to query for the max number of kernels that can be queued up simultaneously.